# How can I print a set of links in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

How can I print a set of links in Chrome or Firefox?

For example, suppose I have a set of webpages,

I have the URLs

I want to print each webpage

How can I do that without manually going to each link and choosing print?

Note-  I don't need any levels of depth so just printing what is at each link, not following links from there.

Comment: so this has been online for 24+12 hours so 36 hours and only has 7 views.  two or three of those views would be mine.

Comment: and 8 views that's me. So a lot of these 8 views are just me checking in surprise that this question has so few views

Comment: Solution I have used is to use firefox 'copy links' extension, to highlight right click and get all the links from selected text.. Then  I put them in a text file b.b, did `wget -t 1 -T 5 -w 3 -i b.b`  Then I had all the files to print. Then I downloaded Print Conductor https://www.print-conductor.com/  and dragged them to that and clicked to print.

Comment: and that is a bit of a workaround 'cos ii was looking for a solution in the browser but that's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have used is to use firefox 'copy links' extension, to highlight right click and get all the links from selected text.. Then I put them in a text file b.b, did `wget -t 1 -T 5 -w 3 -i b.b` Then I had all the files to print. Then I downloaded Print Conductor print-conductor.com and dragged them to that and clicked to print.

(with wget the `-t 1 -T 5 -w 3` are good switches. The -t 1 so if there's some error downloading a file it doesn't keep trying a default of 20 times and not get on with the next one for ages, it tries downloading the file once and if it doesn't manage it it moves on. The -T 5  so if there's an error downloading a file, it wants 5 seconds then moves on, instead of the default of 900 seconds which takes ages until the next one.  The -w 3 so it waits 3 seconds between each file so it doesn't hammer the server causing oneself to get blocked!)

And that is a bit of a workaround 'cos I was looking for a solution in the browser but that's ok